# .pdf files not updating when I use git pull on server although they are updated on github repo

Tags: git, pdf, git-pull

So I am trying to update a .pdf file that I am using on my website (termsandconditions).

What I have done and tried is replacing the .pdf file in the repo which has worked because if I go to the repo and click to display the .pdf file it is the updated one, then when I do git pull on my server it says that there has been a positive 'bit' change so it has recognised that there has been a difference but then when I go to the website and press the button which opens the .pdf directory it shows the outdated file.

I've been trying all sort of changes and none have worked. When I delete the file out of the repo and git pull on the server it still somehow displays the file although it is no longer in the repo.

I am new to git so this is probably a common mistake but I just can't find an answer to this anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> I go to the website

That looks like a [GitHub project page](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages).
If that is the case, the first thing to test is if your browser might have cached the document.

Try and use an [incognito/private mode](https://www.lifewire.com/browsing-incognito-445990) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Yes the issues still persists even in an incognito/private browser

Comment: @DreaM Are you using a GitHub pages site?

Comment: I am not using a GitHub page, I am using my own vps server and a custom url.

Comment: @DreaM Can you SSH to your server, and check the right PDF file is actually there?

Comment: I can ssh but I am not sure how you check if something like a pdf file is in it.

Comment: @DreaM If you know the name of the file, do a `find / -name "yourFile.pdf"`

Comment: I ran it and it came back with a positive directory but as I have deleted the file from github and did git pull that directory is no longer real in Git repo. So I just don't understand why me doing git pull after I update or even delete the file from the Repo does not updated it on server side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251626/discussion-between-vonc-and-dream).